# Using active admin gem for administration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Iam using active admin gem for administration purpose i have included the gems 
      gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
      gem 'devise' 
and the commands
    bundle install
    rails generate active_admin:install 
but when i run the rake db:migrate iam getting following error
    rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

```
 Mysql2::Error: Table 'admin_users' already exists:
 CREATE TABLE `admin_users` (`id` int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
`email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `encrypted_password` varchar(255)
 DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `reset_password_token` varchar(255), `reset_password_sent_at`
 datetime, `remember_created_at` datetime, `sign_in_count` int(11) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
`current_sign_in_at` datetime, `last_sign_in_at` datetime, `current_sign_in_ip`   
 varchar(255), `last_sign_in_ip` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` 
 datetime) ENGINE=InnoDB/home/ameex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-
 4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:301:in `query'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error suggests you have an existing table named admin_users. you may have already attempted an active_admin migration, try resetting your database.

```
rake db:reset
```

Comment: @suganyasangith., When an answer fixes your issue, please dont hesitate to "Accept" the answer. It would help future visitors to use this solution first.

Answer (score 0):

Also, We can do these three steps too.

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

or simply,

`rake db:migrate:reset` => **which runs db:drop db:create db:migrate**